# Polynomials vanishing almost everywhere

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Suppose that $f$ is a function from the prime-order field $\mathbb F_p$ to the field itself. Considering the evaluation map $P\mapsto P(x,f(x))$ and comparing the dimensions, it is easy to show that there exists a bivariate polynomial $P$ of total degree $d<\sqrt{2p}$ such that $P(x,f(x))=0$ for each $x\in\mathbb F_p$.

What I need instead is a low-degree polynomial $P$ such that $P(x,f(x))=0$ holds for *all, but exactly one* value of $x\in\mathbb F_p$.

In general, such a polynomial may fail to exist; say, to have $P(x,x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb F_p$ with one exception, we need $\deg P\ge p-1$.

> What should one require from $f$ to ensure the existence of a polynomial $P$ with, say, $\deg P=O(p^{1/2+\varepsilon})$, such that $P$ vanishes on all, but exactly one point $(x,f(x))$, $x\in\mathbb F_p$?

---

To give the question a more precise shape, suppose that there is a partition $\mathbb F_p=S_1\cup\dotsb\cup S_n$, and a system of (univariate) polynomials $Q_1,\dotsc,Q_n$, such that $f$ coincides with $Q_k$ on $S_k$, for each $k\in[1,n]$. If in this case $P(x,f(x))$ vanishes for all, but one element $x\in\mathbb F_p$, then 
  $$ \textstyle \deg P\ge \min \left\{ \frac{|S_k|-1)}{\deg Q_k}\colon 1\le k\le n \right\}. $$
Thus, a necessary condition for $P$ of degree $\deg P=O(p^{1/2+\varepsilon})$ to exist is that if $f$ is "piecewise polynomial", as we have just described, then $|S_k|=O(p^{1/2+\varepsilon}\deg Q_k)$ for each $k\in[1,n]$. Is some form of this condition also sufficient?

> Making the even stronger assumption that
>     $$ | \{ x\in\mathbb F_p\colon f(x)=Q(x) \} | = O(p^{1/2+\varepsilon} \deg Q) $$
>   for any (non-zero) polynomial $Q$, can we conclude that there exists a polynomial $P$ with $\deg P=O(p^{1/2+\varepsilon})$ such that $P$ vanishes on all, but exactly one point $(x,f(x)),\ x\in\mathbb F_p$?

Comment: This looks like list decoding.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch: Could you expand on this? I cannot see any connection.

Comment: It may not be the same thing but it reminded me of Sudan's algorithm for list decoding of Reed-Solomon codes.